# how do I combine 4 integers into a single integer in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have 4 integers:

```
int i1 = 1, i2 = 8, i3 = 0, i4 = 60;
```

I want to combine them and store into another variable `var1`, so that `var1` would equal `18060`. How do I do this in C++?

Comment: A bit of searching can easily solve this question.

Comment: @Luuklag: If that was so easy and you *did* find something, you could've showed it to the OP and still made your point that he obviously did not much searching by himself.

Comment: @dakab, at the time there was already an answer, that refered to something similar I found, so no need for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
int i1 = 1, i2 = 8, i3 = 0, i4 = 60, var1;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << i1 << i2 << i3 << i4;
ss >> var1;
```

Comment: And if you want to turn that back into a number: `int val = atoi (ss.str().c_str());`

Comment: `operator>>` will do. I'd use what you suggested if I had to use `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing it using `std::stoi` and `std::to_string` (C++11)

```
int var1 = stoi(to_string(i1) + to_string(i2) + to_string(i3) + to_string(i4));
```

Answer (score 0):

As the OP mentioned the tag VC++ it's worth mentoining the below:

```
int i1 = 1, i2 = 8, i3 = 0, i4 = 60;
CString csNumber;
csNumbers.Format(_T("%d%d%d%d"), i1, i2, i3, i4);
int yourNumber = _ttoi((LPCTSTR)csNumbers);
```